# SQL group by date (hour)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table with a "Date" Column. I want to group by hour for a specific date.

Comment: If the date column holds a `DateTime` then how are you going to group by part of the data in the "Date" column?

Comment: @Nick: In Oracle, DATE includes time.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
Select TO_CHAR(date,'HH24')
from table
where date = TO_DATE('20110224', 'YYYYMMDD')
group by TO_CHAR(date,'HH24')
```

Comment: `TO_CHAR`ed dates won't sort properly. Consider using `TRUNC` instead.

Answer (score 60):

You can also do this:

```
SELECT TRUNC(datecol, 'HH24') FROM mytable
GROUP BY TRUNC(datecol, 'HH24');
```

Comment: Another advantage is that the datatype returned by `TRUNC` here is a DATE, so it always sorts correctly - whereas `TO_CHAR` will use alphabetic sorting which will not always be correct depending on what date/time format is used.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want Date/hour (`TRUNC(datecol,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24')` gives error: `SQL Error [1898] [22008]: ORA-01898: too many precision specifiers`)

Comment: @ryvantage, you can't truncate at multiple levels at the same time - if you want to truncate to the nearest day, use `DD`, if you want to truncate to the nearest hour (as per the OP), use `HH24` as per my answer.

Comment: Makes sense. I was just hunting down a different answer.

Comment: I get ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression with my DATE field

Comment: @Wassadamo, that'll be because you have not matched your SELECTed expression with your GROUP BY expression.

Answer (score 5):

```
select to_char(datecol,'HH24') thehour, count(*) count_in_hour
from tbl
where datecol = date '20110224'
group by to_char(datecol,'HH24')
order by thehour asc
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, I would have suggested [EXTRACT (datetime)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions059.htm#SQLRF00639), but (empahsis mine):

> If HOUR, MINUTE, or SECOND is requested, then expr must evaluate to an
>   expression of data type TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, TIMESTAMP
>   WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE, or INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND. *DATE is not valid
>   here*, because Oracle Database treats it as ANSI DATE data type, which
>   has no time fields.

Therefore, the result is a little bit ugly:

```
  SELECT EXTRACT (HOUR FROM CAST (m.a_date AS TIMESTAMP)) AS hour_,
         COUNT (*) AS count_
    FROM MY_TABLE m
GROUP BY EXTRACT (HOUR FROM CAST (m.a_date AS TIMESTAMP));
```