# Conversion of the result in hourly count in the given time frame

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query to achieve below results from the table data:

- Result should be broken in hourly data for the given timeframe.
- count of the purchases for the same time frame last year
- Count of the purchases for the same time frame 3 or 1 week/s prior
- % difference of coulmn 1 compare to YOY (Year Over Year trend)
- % difference of coulmn 1 compare to WOW (Week Over Week trend)

Since I am beginner I can write the query to fetch the data for the data but I can not break the sales into hourly data. Also, I want to compare the sales with YOY and WOW data for the same time frame.

Here is the query to pull the data for the day.

```
select COUNT(*)                               Order_Count_For_The_Day
       FROM
      purchase_Mobile
 WHERE
     CREATE_DATE between to_date('01/02/2018 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and  to_date('01/02/2018 23:59:59','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
      AND status_code >= 99;
```

Can someone please change the query and help me to get the desired output mentioned in the points above, I would be very thankful for the whole life?

I have already tried to pull the data from the given table and I can pull the data for specific time period.

```
select COUNT(*)                               Order_Count_For_The_Day
       FROM
      purchase_Mobile
 WHERE
     CREATE_DATE between to_date('01/02/2018 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and  to_date('01/02/2018 23:59:59','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
      AND status_code >= 99;
```

- Result should be broken in hourly data for the given time-frame.
- count of the purchases for the same time frame last year
- Count of the purchases for the same time frame 3 or 1 week/s prior
- % difference of column 1 compare to YOY (Year Over Year trend)
- % difference of column 1 compare to WOW (Week Over Week trend)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the hourly information, you can use datepart(HH,Create_Date).  Then use a GROUP BY that hourly information.

```
SELECT COUNT(CREATE_DATE)           Order_Count_For_The_Day
    ,datepart(HH,CREATE_DATE)   Order_Hour
    ,MAX(CREATE_DATE)           CurrentDate
        FROM purchase_Mobile
        CREATE_DATE between to_date('01/02/2018 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and  to_date('01/02/2018 23:59:59','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  AND status_code >= 99;

    GROUP BY datepart(HH,CREATE_DATE)
```

In order to do the This Year, Last Year, other time frames - I'd split them into their own temp tables and join them in the end.  There are issues that you'd need to adjust for this (hours without sales, hours closed, etc. that how I have done this would not pick up) but wanted to get you some options to start:

```
    DECLARE @StartDate  DateTime = '2018-1-2 00:00:00'
DECLARE @EndDate    DateTime = '2018-1-2 23:59:00'


DECLARE @CurrentResults Table
(OrderCount INT
,OrderHour INT
,CurrentDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @CurrentResults
SELECT COUNT(CREATE_DATE)           Order_Count_For_The_Day
        ,datepart(HH,CREATE_DATE)   Order_Hour
        ,MAX(CREATE_DATE)           CurrentDate
            FROM purchase_Mobile
            WHERE CREATE_DATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
                        AND status_code >= 99

        GROUP BY datepart(HH,CREATE_DATE)


OPTION (RECOMPILE);

DECLARE @LastYearResults Table
(LastYearOrderCount INT
,LastYearOrderHour INT
,LastYearDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @LYResults
SELECT COUNT(CREATE_DATE)           LastYearOrderCount
        ,datepart(HH,CREATE_DATE)   LastYearOrderHour
        ,MAX(CREATE_DATE)           LastYearDate
            FROM purchase_Mobile
            WHERE CREATE_DATE BETWEEN @StartDate-365 AND @EndDate-365
                        AND status_code >= 99
        GROUP BY datepart(HH,CREATE_DATE)

OPTION (RECOMPILE);

DECLARE @LastWeekResults Table
(LastWeekOrderCount INT
,LastWeekOrderHour INT
,LastWeekDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @LastWeekResults
SELECT COUNT(CREATE_DATE)           Order_Count
        ,datepart(HH,CREATE_DATE)   Order_Hour
        ,MAX(CREATE_DATE)           LastWeekDate
            FROM purchase_Mobile
            WHERE CREATE_DATE BETWEEN @StartDate-7 AND @EndDate-7
                        AND status_code >= 99
        GROUP BY datepart(HH,CREATE_DATE)

OPTION (RECOMPILE);

Select CR.OrderHour
        ,CR.OrderCount
        ,LY.LastYearOrderCount
        ,LW.LastWeekOrderCount
        ,CR.CurrentDate
        ,LY.LastYearDate
        ,LW.LastWeekDate
        FROM @CurrentResults As CR
            LEFT JOIN @LastYearResults AS LY ON LY.LastYearOrderHour = CR.OrderHour
            LEFT JOIN @LastWeekResults AS LW ON LW.LastWeekOrderHour = CR.OrderHour

        ORDER BY CR.OrderHour
```

Comment: Hi @Brian Brooks,
Thank you for the help, but I'm getting below error:
ORA-00904: "DATEPART": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 6

SELECT COUNT(CREATE_DATE)           Order_Count_For_The_Day
    ,datepart(HH,CREATE_DATE)   Order_Hour
    ,MAX(CREATE_DATE)           CurrentDate
        FROM purchase_Mobile
        CREATE_DATE between to_date('01/02/2018 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and  to_date('01/02/2018 23:59:59','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  AND status_code >= 99;

    GROUP BY datepart(HH,CREATE_DATE)

Comment: I am not familiar with the syntax of Oracle, but it looks like your answer for the change you would need can be found here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111396/sql-group-by-date-hour)   
Something like this: 
select COUNT(CREATE_DATE) Order_Count_For_The_Day
    ,TRUNC(CREATE_DATE, 'HH24')   Order_Hour
           FROM purchase_Mobile
     WHERE
         CREATE_DATE between to_date('01/02/2018 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and  to_date('01/02/2018 23:59:59','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
     AND status_code >= 99
GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATE_DATE, 'HH24') 
ORDER BY Order_Hour;

Comment: Hi Brian,
Thank you but I am looking for my data to look like below, providing some sample data in excel: https://www.screencast.com/t/dzEnF0oRLs

The query which you gave, is giving the result like below and this is not the desired output, the desired output should look like above screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/dzEnF0oRLs

click on bothe these link and you would be able to see the screenshots.
Thank you.